# Can we put /boot and /root on separate drives?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

In my laptop, I've 2 drives. 1 is NVMe Intel Optane SSD of 16Gb and another is 1TB HDD. Currently, /home is mounted to 1TB HDD and Linux File system is mounted on SSD. I want to mount only /boot to the SSD and everything else (/root and /home) to HDD. Is it possible that out of entire Linux, /boot is on SSD and /root (and everything else) is on separate HDD? During installation of Ubuntu, can I select /boot to be on SSD and / (just slash) to be on HDD?
(16GB is very less and I can very quickly fill that if I install good amount of apps. But the SSD is fast, so I want /boot on that and everything else on HDD)

Comment: Short answer is “yes”. If you choose “Something else” during the OS installation, you can specify where everything goes. One word of warning, though: if you choose to micromanage where the system stored data, be sure to consider beforehand the sort of applications you will use. There is good reason to fully optimize the Optane storage, but there are consequences when you run out 

Comment: Yes, but `/boot` needs not more than 1GB, so on your 16GB drive, you could put more stuff, e.g. `/var` and `/tmp`. If you put everything apart from `/home`, the 16 GB is a bit narrow. Or maybe a swap partition if you're low on memory.

Comment: Do not that `/root` and the root directory `/` are very different directories.  `/root` is a user directory (for the root user) and is usually tiny; where as `/` is the root directory and contains everything that isn't placed elsewhere.

Comment: The boot process involves more than just the contents of /boot. Hard to know what proportion of the benefit of an ssd you would get from /boot alone being on it. I’d be inclined to place everything on the ssd and remove software that you don’t need. I haven’t installed for a while but you used to be able to specify a minimal install and add what you need from there.

Comment: yeah that's the issue. If I keep everything except /home on SSD, I'll run out of storage on SSD since programs won't be stored on /home. 
So basically, can we do this during installation:
SSD:  /boot ; 
HDD: /root (or just slash "/", please guide). And if yes, what complication it might have?

Comment: As @guiverc says / and /root are different. /root is within / and just contains the root user information. It will take very little space. / is everything else except any directories that you specifically mount from a different partition. You can do what you ask, SSD: /boot. ; HDD: /  but this has three consequences. 1. The usage of the SSD will be less than 1 GB. 2. All binaries and applications will run from the HDD at HDD speeds. 3. The speed of boot is unpredictable and may be much slower that you expect. Only the images in the /boot directory will be read at SSD speeds

Comment: The consequences are acceptable in my case as long as I am able to install softwares and stuff without worrying about SSD getting full (in case I nount / on ssd), which by the way, I faced once when I have setup my laptop with required softwares and had 15 to 20 apps. 5-10 seconds delay would be acceptable I think. Thanks a lot all of you for your guidance :)

Answer (score 3):

First, a little deduction: The question's confusion between `/root` (the root account's directory) and `/` (the filesystem root directory, which has nothing to do with the root account) suggests that you are a new user.

The phrasing of the question suggests that you are in the process of making a classic new-user mistake: Over-planning and over-partitioning. Your previous Windows experience will generally lead you to wrong answers, since Windows and Linux work quite differently.

**Advice #1**: Make your first install *successful*, not *perfect*. Keep it simple. Go with the installer defaults, even if they are not quite what you want yet. Once you can successfully install, then turn-round and use your experience to re-install with the customizations or additional complexity that you want.

**Advice #2**: New power-users coming from Windows often love that Linux distros let you see and poke all the spinning gears. However, poking your finger into spinning gears will injure your finger and break the machine. So keep your hands in your pockets and don't poke something until you have researched what you are poking and what the consequences are. And keep proper backups so you can restore the machine when you break it.

**Advice #3**: Many new power-users who customize their install decide to backup-and-repartition after a few months of experience. Their partition usage sizes don't match their original estimates, so one partition is full while another is nearly empty. Be prepared to admit that your guesses about the future might not be accurate predictions, and prepare accordingly.

**Advice #4**: Most laptop users suspend or hibernate rather than fully poweroff or reboot. With longer battery life, I've seen suspend replace hibernation among my peers. So maybe a `/boot` partition on SSD is important...and maybe it's not. Keep in mind that the `/boot` partition contains ONLY the Linux kernel --and not the many GB of the rest of the operating system-- so putting it on the SSD may not speed your boot as much as you hope. You have all the tools you need to try /boot on both SSD and HDD, to time each method, and make your own decision...if you know how to use those tools.

**Advice #5**: For most general-purpose users, 16GB is plenty for everything *outside* of your `/home` directory. `/home` is where you store all your movies and music and mail and other voluminous data. So `/home` on the big HDD and everything else on the smaller SSD. Try that simple configuration before diving too deep into more complex alternatives.